# How do I optimize my random forest model in scikit Learn (Python)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have a random forest model using scikit learn, as seen here:

```
model = RandomForestClassifier(criterion='gini',n_estimators=700,min_samples_split=4,min_samples_leaf=1,max_features='auto',oob_score=True,random_state=1,n_jobs=-1)
model.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred_rm=model.predict(X_test)
print('--------------The Accuracy of the model---------------------------')
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=22)
result_rm = cross_val_score(model, all_features, Targeted_feature, cv=10, scoring = 'accuracy')
print('The cross validated score for Random Forest Classifier is:',round(result_rm.mean()*100,2))
y_pred = cross_val_predict(model,all_features,Targeted_feature,cv=10)
kfold = KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=22)
result_rm1 = cross_val_score(model, all_features, Targeted_feature, cv=5, scoring='accuracy')
print('The cross validated score (5)for Random Forest Classifier is:',round(result_rm1.mean()*100,2))
sns.heatmap(confusion_matrix(Targeted_feature,y_pred),annot=True,fmt='3.0f',cmap="winter")
plt.title('Confusion_matrix', y=1.05, size=15)
```

I've been trying to optimize my model, but haven't had any success yet. The highest accuracy rate I have achieved on the test dataset is 78%. Do you have any ideas or steps I could take to improve my model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as if you have tried hyper-parameter tuning. What makes you think you can achieve an accuracy score higher than 78%? If you compute the accuracy score when trying to predict on the training set, do you get near 100% accuracy? If so, then this is a problem of *overfitting*, and you might try and reduce the number of trees in your RandomForest.

If you don't get a very high training accuracy, then maybe the features you have are not good enough to predict on the data and you might consider collecting more features. This problem is called *underfitting*.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using hyperparameter tuning if not try using GridSearchCV or RandomizedSearchCV from sklearn. Even then if you can't improve your model score try using XGboost or do feature engineering to find useful features to make the prediction.

I hope you have done all necessary data preprocessing, if not do them which are very important. Try other Machine learning models also there is a chance they may perform better.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried some other models and this one has performed the best. I'll definitely try xgboost or the other sklearn hyperparameter tuning featuers